# Possible to trigger JavaScript function on page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trigger a JavaScript function when a user tries to reload the current page?

Comment: What does this mean? What do you want to do? Do you mean *call a* JavaScript function?

Comment: clarification pls? write javascript on reload? what does that mean? dymnamically write JS? or do you mean reload page using JS

Comment: @fskreuz: No, when user click the  reload tab in browser, I want to execute an function before execution reload current page

Comment: Is it okay if the function is executed every time the page is navigated away from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean confirm an "unload" whereby execute a function before the user leaves the current page.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function mymessage()
{
    //this is the sample function code executed on "unload"
    alert("This message was triggered from the onunload event")
}
</script>
</head>

<body onunload="mymessage()">

<p>close this window</p>
</body>

</html>
```

OR

the jQuery version http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Answer (score 1):

it difficult to infer what exactly do you want but as you stated in the comments that you want a function to execute before the page gets refreshed you can use [`unload`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});
```